# How to merge two files line by line using a delimiter in bash

Tags: unix, awk

I would like to merge two input files using comma delimiter and write into a new file. How can I implement this in bash? Here is the sample data as below. Any inputs/suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

**

```
 - What I have tried?
```

**

**`paste -d ' , ' file1 file2 > file3`**

`Input Data`**`strong text`**

```
file1            file2
1,A               10    
2,B               20    
3,C               30
```

**`Desired Output`**

```
file3
1,A,10
2,B,20
3,C,30
```

Comment: `paste -d ',' file1 file2 > file3` works fine for me.  What's wrong on your end?

Comment: It works fine...thnx

Comment: It will NOT work as expected if your text files are in DOS format.  Without the  '-d' option, there is a carriage return as well as a tab between the columns.  With -d , you'll only get ,second column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
paste -d ' , ' file1 file2 > file3
```

Answer (score 0):

First..... Paste is meant to paste as many files as you like after eachother, line-by-line. By default it puts tabs between the lines from each of the files.

```
  line-from-file-1<tab>line-from-file2<tab>line-from-file3
```

When you specify "-d" you specify what to use instead of each of the tabs. So when pasting three files, you need two separators, so for example -d '@#' will result in:

```
  line-from-file-1@line-from-file2#line-from-file3
```

So when you specify -d ' , ' you indicated that you wanted a space between the first and second file, a comma between the second and third and again a space between the third and fourth file.... That's exactly what happens.

Someone mentions the dos-format line endings. I just ran into that as well. I used:

```
  fromdos file1
```

to convert the first file's line endings. I got the tool from the tofrodos package. The second file you oddly get away with the dos-line-endings, because they seem to get stripped of automatically somehow. It would be neater to process both input files like this beforehand.